# Volume of a bounded open set in $\Bbb{R}^n$

Tags: measure-theory

1. What is the definition of a "bounded open set in $\Bbb{R}^n$"? In $\Bbb{R}$, we have intervals, like $(a, b)$ where $a, b \in \Bbb{R}$. How does it look in higher dimensions?
2. What exactly does it mean to say that "a bounded open set in $\Bbb{R}^n$ has a finite positive volume"? What is the definition of the set's volume?

What I had in mind so far? So... I guess that the sign of the volume is related to the orientation of the set, although I don't have a mental image or a definition that helps me imagine it. Rather than the orientation, I'm not sure what information is being added when writing that a bounded open set in $\Bbb{R}^n$ "has a finite positive volume"; If the open set is bounded, then necessarily it should have a finite volume, right?

Comment: Since it is bounded, you can draw a box around it. Boxes have finite volume (product of side lengths). Your set is even smaller, so that has finite volume too.

Comment: Yes, any bounded open set has finite positive volume, there is no negative volume (and it is not $0$ since there is a ball around any point of an open set)

Answer (score 1):

1. To understand the notion of boundedness in higher dimensions, the first thing you need to understand is the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$, defined by $||\mathbf{x}|| := (x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2)^{1/2}$. Note that when $n=1$ this is the usual absolute value! A subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded if there exists some positive constant $B>0$ such that $||\mathbf{x}||< B$ for every $x\in S$. Geometrically, a set is bounded if it fits inside some $n-$dimensional ball centered at the origin. (Think about the cases $n=1,2,3$ for intuition).
2. Your second question is actually very profound. First of all, the *volume* of a set is always a non negative quantity (so positive means $\neq 0$), but it is not clear how one should define it. Ideally, the volume of a box should be the product of the lengths of the sides in each dimension, and one would like the volume function to satisfy some properties (invariant under translation and additive on disjoint subsets). The following video gives a nice introduction of what the volume (Lebesgue measure) in the real line should satisfy and the problems arising from the desired properties.
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llnNaRzuvd4&list=PLo4jXE-LdDTQq8ZyA8F8reSQHej3F6RFX&index=1